# PoI filter Data WireCloud

Tags: fiware, fiware-wirecloud

I'm using WireCloud, I'm trying to connect the output of a Map Viewer (PoI selected) to the input of a WebBrowser Widget (filter the PoI and get the URL of the image field). I saw some examples on the web doing it, but I'm not able to find the operator. Does anybody knows where can I get it?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had custom operators for that tasks, and I've been cleaning and updating code to publish it as a new operator.

Such operator is called Value Filter, and you can find it on: https://github.com/Wirecloud/value-filter-operator

It does require a preference in dot-sepparated syntax as the **path** to the data you want to filter. It does receive a JSON object, extracts the path-addressed data and outputs it, so it can be instantiated in-line. In case original data is a POI, the path should be something like `poi.data.something`.

Best regards